# Conda install dlib AVX support

Tags: conda, avx, dlib

I've just installed `dlib` using `conda` from the `conda-forge` channel. Is it possibile to know whether it has been built with AVX support?

Answer (score 2):

Just Googled it and it seems it doesn't support. Look at [this link](https://github.com/menpo/conda-dlib)

> The following dlib functionality is disabled for the automated builds:
>
> ```
> SSE4 for 32-bit builds
> AVX
> GUI support
> BLAS on Windows (otherwise MKL is assumed via Anaconda numpy)
> LAPACK on Windows (otherwise MKL is assumed via Anaconda numpy)
> ```
>
> This functionality is disabled in order to attempt to increase the
>   probability that the automated builds will be useful for as large a
>   range of people as possible.

Comment: Are this the same one from the `conda-forge` channel? Anyway in case they're not maybe tha same reasoning applies.